# How to pass a range to the :bd command in a buffer in which a fold has been created?

Tags: command-line

I'm looking for a command to delete a range of buffers.

I launch vim which opens a new unnamed buffer.
I then switch to a file on which I previously put the mark `N` (`~/Dropbox/notes`).

In this file I've written:

```
:e /tmp/foo
:e /tmp/bar
:e /tmp/baz
:e /tmp/qux
:e /tmp/norf
```

I visually select those five lines, and source them (`:<c-u>@*`).

Now I've got 5 new buffers.

I switch back to the `N` file and do a listing (`ls`):

```
  1  h   "[No Name]"                    line 1
  2 %a   "Dropbox/notes"                line 139
  3  h   "/tmp/foo"                     line 1
  4  h   "/tmp/bar"                     line 1
  5  h   "/tmp/baz"                     line 1
  6  h   "/tmp/qux"                     line 1
  7 #h   "/tmp/norf"                    line 1
```

I want to delete the 5 temporary buffers from 3 to 7.
Most Ex commands accept a range, and I suppose `:bd` is probably one of them. I may have misunderstood the help but it seems to confirm you can prefix `:bd` with a range :

> :N,Mbdelete[!]    Do ":bdelete[!]" for all buffers in the range N to M
>         inclusive.

So, I type `:3,7bd` but the result is not what I expected.

All the buffers from 2 to 7 were deleted, including my `N` file and I'm automatically sent back to the unnamed buffer n° 1.
Here's the final output of `:ls`:

```
  1 %a   "[No Name]"                    line 1
```

I tried other ranges like `5,6` but the result is always the same, everything is unloaded except the first buffer.

Is it possible to pass a range to the `:bd` command, and if so how ?

**Edit**:

I think I've found the cause of the problem, but I don't understand it.
It seems to happen only inside a buffer in which a fold has been created.

Here's how to reproduce it:

- create a file `/tmp/test` in which you put :

  `:e /tmp/foo
  :e /tmp/bar
  :e /tmp/baz
  :e /tmp/qux
  :e /tmp/norf`
- launch vim with an empty vimrc and edit the file `/tmp/test`:

  `vim -u NONE /tmp/test`
- source it to open 5 new buffers: `:so%`
- go back to first buffer (`/tmp/test`): `:b1`
- fold the whole buffer: `ggzfG`
- type `:ls`:

    `1 %a   "/tmp/test"                    line 1
    2      "/tmp/foo"                     line 1
    3      "/tmp/bar"                     line 1
    4      "/tmp/baz"                     line 1
    5      "/tmp/qux"                     line 1
    6 #    "/tmp/norf"                    line 1`
- type `:3,4bd` to delete buffers from 3 to 4 (bar and baz).

On my system, vim deletes 5 buffers (1 to 5) instead of 2.

After that the output of `:ls` is:

  `6 %a   "/tmp/norf"                    line 1`

If I don't fold the buffer, the `:bd` command interprets the range as expected.

I'm using vim [version 7.4.942](https://paste.debian.net/plain/343732) installed from this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/ubuntu/dev).

Why is the behavior of the `:bd` command modified when executed inside a buffer in which a fold has been created ?

Comment: what vim version is this?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I'm using vim version 7.4.942. I've edited my question because I think the problem comes from creating a fold inside a buffer.

Comment: The question (and its editing) was quite insightful, hope more people will upvote it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is mentioned briefly at `:h fold-behaviour`

```
For Ex commands the range is adjusted to always start at the first line of a
closed fold and end at the last line of a closed fold.  Thus this command:
    :s/foo/bar/g
when used with the cursor on a closed fold, will replace "foo" with "bar" in
all lines of the fold.
```

I can see, how this is confusing, but I am not sure, if this qualifies as a bug.

Comment: To see if I got that right, if I have a fold from lines 2 to 10, and I run `:3,4bd`, this actually gets replaced to something equivalent to `:2,10bd` ?

Comment: yes, i believe this is what happens.

Comment: In any case, I just made a patch. Let's see what Bram thinks.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thank you very much for the patch ! I really hope it will be accepted, because it's really annoying for someone who uses folds. Even outside of the fold, the range is still modified. Inside the `test` buffer, when I add `" hello world !` on a new line, under the fold, and put the cursor under it to be clearly outside of the fold, `:3,4bd` is still modified to `:1,5bd`. If you've got favorite files on which you put some marks, and you replace `:bd` with `:bw` you can lose all your marks.

Comment: @saginaw It does not really matter, where the cursor is, just if the range given falls into a folded region.

Comment: should be fixed with [7.4.1035](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v7.4.1035)